# ORA-00932 error. Not sure how to fix

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00932

I'm attempting to run this Oracle query...

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as total, 
         q1 
    FROM exit_responses 
   WHERE sdate BETWEEN '03-Aug-10 12:00:00 AM' AND '03-Nov-10 12:00:00 AM' 
GROUP BY q1;
```

...but I keep getting this error...

```
Error starting at line 3 in command:
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, q1 FROM exit_responses WHERE sdate BETWEEN '03-Aug-10 12:00:00 AM' AND '03-Nov-10 12:00:00 AM' GROUP BY q1 
Error at Command Line:3 Column:130
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Anyone have any ideas? Says it's an inconsistent data type... but I guess I'm not understanding completely.

Thanks

Btw, here's the DESC of my exit_responses table:

```
DESC exit_responses
Name                           Null     Type                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------------------------ -------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
SDATE                                   DATE                                                                                                                                                                                          
F_NAME                                  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)                                                                                                                                                                            
L_NAME                                  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)                                                                                                                                                                            
TITLE                                   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)                                                                                                                                                                            
DEPARTMENT                              VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)                                                                                                                                                                            
EMP_TYPE                                VARCHAR2(11 CHAR)                                                                                                                                                                             
LENGTH_OF_SERVICE                       VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)                                                                                                                                                                            
Q1                                      CLOB()                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q2                                      CLOB()                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q2_OTHER                                CLOB()                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q3_PAY                                  NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q3_HOLIDAYS                             NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q3_VACATION                             NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q3_SICK                                 NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q3_INSURANCE                            NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q3_RETIREMENT                           NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q3_FSA                                  NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q4_AVAILABILITY                         NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q4_QUALITY                              NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q4_SATISFACTION                         NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q4_COMMENTS                             NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q5_ORIENTATION                          NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q5_POLICIES                             NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q5_PROMOTIONAL                          NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q6_JOBDUTIES                            NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q6_RELATIONSHIPS                        NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q6_COOPERATION                          NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q6_EQUIPMENT                            NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q6_CONDITIONS                           NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q6_SAFETY                               NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q7                                      NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q8_KNOWLEDGE                            NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q8_DELEGATION                           NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q8_OBSERVANCE                           NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q8_FEEDBACK                             NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q8_CONTRIBUTIONS                        NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q8_LISTENED                             NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q8_COMPLAINTS                           NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q9                                      VARCHAR2(3 CHAR)                                                                                                                                                                              
Q9_DESCRIBE                             CLOB()                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q10                                     CLOB()                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q11                                     NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q11_COMMENTS                            CLOB()                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q12                                     NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
Q12_DESCRIBE                            CLOB()                                                                                                                                                                                        
ADDITIONAL_COMMENTS                     CLOB()
```

Comment: #1 - accept some answers to your questions.  #2 - post your 'desc exit_responses'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the data type of the SDATE column?  Assuming it is a DATE, you almost certainly want to use explicit TO_DATE calls to convert your strings to dates, i.e.

```
WHERE sdate BETWEEN to_date('03-Aug-2010', 'DD-MON-YYYY') 
                AND to_date( '03-Nov-2010', 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
```

Since midnight is the default time when none is specified, you don't necessarily need the 12:00:00 AM bit.  If you want to include that

```
WHERE sdate BETWEEN to_date('03-Aug-2010 12:00:00 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') 
                AND to_date( '03-Nov-2010 12:00:00 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM' )
```

If SDATE is a DATE and you want the BETWEEN to take two different Unix epochs (milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970) rather than strings, you would want something like

```
WHERE sdate BETWEEN date '1970-01-01' + :1/86400000  
                AND date '1970-01-01' + :2/86400000
```

where :1 and :2 are the two bind variables.  If your epochs are seconds since Jan 1, 1970

```
WHERE sdate BETWEEN date '1970-01-01' + :1/86400  
                AND date '1970-01-01' + :2/86400
```

Comment: Is there anyway to convert a unix timestamp using to_date? It seems bulky to convert from timestamp to string with php, then convert the string to a date w/ to_date().

Comment: If you're talking about a Unix epoch (i.e. the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970), you just need Oracle date arithmetic.

date '1970-01-01' + <<unix_epoch>>/ 86400000 

yields the Oracle date corresponding to the specified <<unix epoch>>

Comment: Actually... I had it as TIMESTAMP column type... now it won't work any of my queries when I changed it to DATE column type. What should I have it as? (which would be best)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Unix Epoch for timestamp. Can I just do WHERE sdate BETWEEN $start AND $end? $start and $end being unix timestamps?

Comment: Either a TIMESTAMP or a DATE should work (you'd need to provide more information about the error(s) you were getting before I could see why a TIMESTAMP would cause problems).  The only real difference between a DATE and a TIMESTAMP in Oracle is that a TIMESTAMP contains sub-second precision and may contain a time zone (if you declare it as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE).  If you don't need either of those, a DATE is probably easier to deal with.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the syntax for doing the BETWEEN comparison on start and end values that are Unix epochs.

Comment: So mine would be WHERE sdate BETWEEN date '1970-01-01' + 1277960400/86400000 AND date '1970-01-01' + 1288674000/86400000 ? What column type do I need to be using? timestamp or date?

Comment: SDATE can be either a DATE or a TIMESTAMP.  It appears that your Unix epochs are actually seconds since 1970, not milliseconds.  So you would want BETWEEN date '1970-01-01' + 1277960400/86400 AND date '1970-01-01' + 1288674000/86400

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm gonna try to use that get it working. :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `sdate`'s date type is Oracle DATE, use the [TO_DATE function](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) to convert a string to a DATE in Oracle:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as total, 
         q1 
    FROM exit_responses 
   WHERE sdate BETWEEN TO_DATE('03-Aug-10 12:00:00 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH12:MI:SS AM') 
                   AND TO_DATE('03-Nov-10 12:00:00 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH12:MI:SS AM') 
GROUP BY q1;
```

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that `sdate` is a DATE or DATETIME column, in which case you need to convert your date strings:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as total,  
         q1  
    FROM exit_responses  
   WHERE sdate BETWEEN to_date('03-Aug-10 12:00:00 AM') AND to_date('03-Nov-10 12:00:00 AM')  
GROUP BY q1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing anything about ORACLE, I would bet that you in fact can't `GROUP BY` on `CLOB` fields.  It makes perfect sense...

Also, look at [this](http://cognitivecache.blogspot.com/2008/11/oracle-sql-group-by-on-portion-of-clob.html).  Excerpt:

> This was significant from Oracle perspective because you cannot do a group by on a clob. In order to do a group by, you need to be able to sort and clob fields do not have a natural sort order. The workaround is to do a to_char function on the clob field but you can get a max of 4000 chars. For me, this suited the requirement because the substring I needed was a small string. But the issue is that I needed to sort a portion of an XML tag inside the clob field and group them based on that. Not only that I needed to find a specific type of error in the XML message and count them.

Comment: Daniel, you are correct. `LOB` s cannot be used in a `GROUP BY` clause. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702

Answer (score 0):

i think, it's better to use to_date function for that.

```
where sdate between
  TO_DATE('03.08.2010:00:00:0','DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('03.10.2010:00:00:0','DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
```